# What is the difference between General Domain and Specific Domain in Text Summarization?

Tags: text, dns, nlp, summarization

I am learning about text summarization and understand there are different domains example: news, email, medical, scientific papers etc. What examples fall under general domain ?

Comment: General domain means working in all specific domains! : )

Comment: @OmG thanks, I guess it makes sense, just couldn't figure it out.